# How to place a view upon a navigation view controller?

Tags: iphone, uiview, uinavigationcontroller

I'm designing UI for iPhone application.How should i places a UIView object upon a Navigation ViewController?

Suppose viewObj is the UIView object and uiNavControllerObj is Navigation controllet object?what is the syntax to place  viewObj onto uiNavControllerObj?

```
UIView* viewObj;
NavigationController* uiNavControllerObj;
```

Edited Question :

```
Can i achieve this by this syntax? 
uiNavControllerObj.view = viewObj;// is this the proper way to achieve 
[rootviewObj addSubview:uiNavControllerObj.view]; 
[uiwindowObj addSubview:rootViewObj];
```

Comment: is this correct

uiNavController.view = viewObj;

Answer (score 1):

UINavigationControllers don't deal with UIViews, they deal with UIViewControllers.

Typical usage if your UIViewController is the root (first) view controller:

```
MyRootViewController *myRootViewController = [[MyRootViewController alloc] init];
UINavigationController *navController = [UINavigationController initWithRootViewController:myRootViewController];
```

UINavigationController uses a stack to keep track of the ViewControllers it manages. If you want to push another onto the stack (for example, drilling down through a Table View Controller), you would do it from inside the View Controller on top of the stack as such:

```
AnotherViewController *anotherController = [[AnotherViewController alloc] init];
// every view controller has a reference to it's Navigation Controller
[self.navigationController pushViewController:anotherController];
```

Alternatively, and I'm only putting this because your question isn't very clear, you can overlay a Navigation Controller with a Modal View Controller. Other than that I'm not really sure what else you would mean by putting a view "on top of" a nav controller.

Comment: Hello bpapa, thanks for your reply, what i meant is, i've created a window object[uiWindowObj] and i'm adding uiNavControllerObj[ViewController] as subView to rootViewObj[of type UIView] and a rootViewObj as subView to window.Then i've created a viewObj[UIView], which i want to add as subview to uiNavControllerObj. 



I've written the code in the above section. Edited question. plz tel me can i achieve it by doing that. is the syntax proper?

Comment: There's no such type as NavigationController. It's UINavigationController. The way to add views to it is in my answer. Take a look at this for more: http://developer.apple.com/IPhone/library/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UINavigationController_Class/Reference/Reference.html